# Question about some inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $p(t)>0, \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$; $p(t)$ is continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{p(s)}<+\infty,$ $a_1, a_2, b_1,b_2$ nonnegative real numbers satisfying $D=a_1b_2+a_2b_1+a_1a_2>0$.
Define the following functions as

$\theta(t)=b_1+a_1\int_{-\infty}^{t}\frac{ds}{p(s)}$

and

$\varphi(t)=b_2+a_2\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{p(s)}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

So, $\theta'(t)=\frac{a_1}{p(t)}$ and $\varphi'(t)=-\frac{a_2}{p(t)}$; $\theta(t)$ is increasing and $\varphi(t)$ is decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$. $(a_1+a_2>0)$.

I am confused about the inequalities,

$\theta(t)+\varphi(t)<\theta(\infty)+\varphi(-\infty)$

or

$\theta(t)+\varphi(t)\leq\theta(\infty)+\varphi(-\infty)$;

Can anyone explain me that it should be inequality or strict inequality?

Note: this is not a homework question, so if the answer is clear I'd really be appreciated knowing why. 
Thank you.